# Is it possible to implement Proximity Profile without GATT?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, proximity, gatt

I'm interesting in Proximity Profile services on top of the BR/EDR profiles instead of the GATT. I'm talking about Windows Bluetooth Stack (Windows 7) that is not supporting BLE APIs.

Questions:

1. Is it possible?
2. Can you point me on the specific implementation?
3. Is there 3rd party solution that can help (I*'m talking about non-BLE radio that is shipped with Windows 7 laptops)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think they're 2 completely separate things.  You can implement both at the same time or just one or just the other.  I think the proximity profile just requires advertising where GATT requires you to connect to a device to read attributes.

**EDIT:**
It helps to read the spec before answering.  ^_^

Just glancing at it, it seems that the proximity thing works by making a regular connection and then sending an alert when the connection is loss.  It uses the GATT to configure options related to it.  So, for example, you could configure the alert level given.

As for doing this over BR/EDR, I don't know.  You can access GATT over BR/EDR, but I'm not sure if that's covered by the profile.  The linked profile talks only about BLE and references to BR/EDR is to compare it with BLE.

Comment: According to [Proximity Profile Spec](http://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=239392), in Section "1.1 Profile Dependency" written, and I quote "This profile requires the Generic Attribute Profile (GATT)."

Comment: I guess you answered your own question then.  ;)  However, you could implement a system that detected the presence of other devices by simply listening to advertising packets and estimating distance by the RSSI values.  I thought that's what it did and that wouldn't require GATT.

Comment: @TimTisdall: Its a good trick to approximate the distance by reading RSSI levels through advertisement packets, but there comes the limitation when the rssi settings are changed in the device which is advertising, the device which is scanning needs modifications in the LuukUp Table kind of thing if its implemented that way.